# Show tab options in all screens using fragment approach

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-tab-host

I am creating android music player app.
I need to show main four options as tab.
station
artist
search
more

I have experience to create same type of  application with tab host and tab activity.
I have gone through documentation for fragment,fragment activity before starting this app.

My question is if I go for fragment can I show tab option in all screens started from previous one.
Suppose i select search option and then I click on play song from dynamic list view and if after that I select any song item from list I want to display tab option in new music play screen also.
Please help as this is design issue and I know only experience one can help me in such case.

My question is:
Have you  achieved this behavior to enable tab options in all screens?
Any demo?
Please suggest me right way to achieve this.
This time I want to go as per android dev guide line.

Note:
In my previous app I achieved tab option enable using  through setcontnetview through  and visible option of layout and also my custom adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ActionBar navigation tabs to achieve what you want

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs

Comment: and there is no need of fragment ?

Comment: your screens will be fragments and you just have to add your tabs code inside the main activity then switch between the fragments (screens)

Comment: Hi Mahdi,I successfully created fragment and tab using abs library.
Now I need to populate my list view of fragment with server side response and start music player(which is another fragment) on based of selection.Can you please help.I need to know in which method we can write this code and can we call other fragment same as activity?Still little bit confused about design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use TabHosts they are deprecated use ActionBar tab-navigation, it has also the advantage, that the ActionBar can be called, changed, removed etc. all over the application